# Which is faster? SharedPreference or File in android

Tags: android, file, sharedpreferences

I have Long Text that I've saved it in file. My Question is if I Read Directly from file is Fast or for First time I save it in SharedPreference and for next time I read from SharedPreference is Fast?

Comment: So far what have you read about the `SharedPreference`? Could you show us your research, things like its format, etc?

Comment: Shared preferences are stored in a XML-file! It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Write your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that speed will be your only concern. If it is, than Sharedprefs looks faster too me. However you are talking about millisecs difference here.

To be sure, use log to capture time and start measuring.

You should be more concerned about other stuff, like the amount of data you are going to write, the sort of data. Etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

SharedPrefs is faster,basically it store the value with key pair.you can't do everything in Sharedprefs.u have to choose depends upon requirements
for more details go to the link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html